# Is there a difference in performance between drawing a scaled image versus a regular image?

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, cpu

I am asking this question in hopes of better understanding performance.

I am creating an Android game, and I am noticing a significant drop in frame rate when I draw a static 1280x720 background stored in memory. GC is not called during this drop, so I assume that it is not a memory issue, but a CPU issue.

To remedy this problem, I tried reducing the image to half its size (640x360). Frame rate improves by about 33%; however, when I dynamically scale this reduced image back up to the 1280x720 dimensions, the frame rate drops back down.

My question is this: In terms of CPU rendering performance, does it matter what resolution the image stored in memory is? Or does the CPU have the same workload whether you draw a 1280x720 image directly versus a 640x360 image scaled by 2?

Furthermore, how could I improve performance without changing the overall resolution of my frame? I find it odd that a Galaxy Nexus cannot consistently maintain 60 FPS with just a single 1280 x 720 image on the screen.

Comment: Maybe you should use OpenGL?

Comment: Try making the image a power of two and then scaling it

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com - I should start going that route. Haha.
Codejoy - I've been doing that using option.inSampleSize = 2, but it results in less memory consumption but no performance gain.